# Formula for coming up with a final time

Tags: excel

I just want to ask if it's possible to make a formula that will result to a final time that I need? If possible, how can I do it?

For example, if a time is after business hours today, the formula should add a certain number of hours to have a result of 8AM the following day, else, add zero hours. Consider this as a reverse of time difference formula.

Thanks in advance. Just need this to set SLA deadlines for work.

Comment: @pnuts I did, but it ended up adding hours to requests received within business hours. so I decided to take it to a different direction then just make sure to add hours to reach 8AM timestamp then I'll add another set of hours for the actual deadline.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps for you, Please alter working hours in the formula per your needs,
[image]

Formula,

`=TEXT(IF(AND(D2>TIME(8,0,0),D2<TIME(17,0,0)),D2,TIME(8,0,0)),"hh:mm")`

Comment: Hi, noted. Will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @user7660029 Thanks!! Please upvote if you found this helpful and mark the answer as correct f it works